# Get Aggregate Results instead of Events from Splunk REST API

Tags: json, api, rest, curl, splunk

Having trouble querying Splunk API for a set of events by day. My goal is to return JSON with seven days of event counts (impressions and uniques) for a set of server logs. The search is as follows:

```
index=assets_index gid=30 | timechart count(clientip) AS Impressions dc(clientip) AS Uniques
```

When I run this search, and get the results in terminal:

```
curl -u admin:ourpass -k https://ourserver.com:8089/services/search/jobs -d"search=search index=assets_index gid=30 | timechart count(clientip) AS Impressions dc(clientip) AS Uniques"
curl -u admin:ourpass \
     -k https://ourserver.com:8089/services/search/jobs/1357597855.2304/results/ \
     --get -d output_mode=json
```

I get the raw events from the search and not the results (running this in the Web search App returns the results I want). I'm sure there's an easy way to request results that gets this to work, but I can't find it. Help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are very close ... just the way you are passing parameters is wrong. Each request parameter should be passed individually with the -d flag AND the parameter values need to be URL-encoded. Try this and see if it works right for you:

`curl -u admin:ourpass -k https://ourserver.com:8089/services/search/jobs -d search="search index%3Dassets_index gid%3D30 | timechart count(clientip) AS Impressions dc(clientip) AS Uniques`"

Not sure what language is your webapp in, Splunk also has [SDKs](http://dev.splunk.com/view/sdks/SP-CAAADP7) in multiple languages. It might be easier to go through the SDKs and let them handle talking to Splunk.